# Arduino speaking bot with talkie library

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I am working on an Arduino talking bot which says some basic words from the Talkie library.
I saw this project from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Gk-7JKFXU)

I want to input the words from my smartphone via Bluetooth and make the Arduino speak it.

The words in the Talkie library has these kinds of format - sp2_DANGER, sp3_ZONE etc. I edited the library and removed the sp2_/3 etc so that we have to type the main words only.

I am using a Bluetooth terminal app for Android to send the data.

**The main problem** is when I send the data it is read perfectly by Arduino (When I comment the talkie say function ) but when I make Talkie library to speak the words it shows an error:-

**exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'Talkie::say(String&)'**

**My code:-**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "Talkie.h"

#include <Arduino.h>

extern const uint8_t DANGER[] PROGMEM = {0x0A,0x28,0x30,0x6C,0xD4,0xC7,0x54,0x19,0xAA,0x9B,0xD5,0x34,0x6B,0xCA,0xEE,0x6B,0x56,0xDD,0xBD,0xA9,0x44,0xAC,0x59,0xD5,0x08,0xC1,0x9C,0xB1,0x7A,0x65,0x33,0x24,0x72,0xE7,0xAC,0x95,0x8C,0x64,0xE0,0x13,0x95,0x57,0xD4,0xBD,0x50,0x8D,0x45,0x19,0x51,0xB3,0x98,0x61,0xAE,0x64,0xA4,0xCD,0x60,0x94,0x85,0xD2,0x90,0x47,0x41,0x35,0xEA,0xEA,0x5A,0x73,0x4A,0x99,0xA0,0x38,0x09,0xC0,0x76,0x42,0xA3,0x9C,0xDA,0x94,0x35,0xF2,0x8C,0xB1,0x66,0x25,0x0D,0xDB,0x3C,0x86,0x9A,0x4B,0xA0,0x35,0xFB,0x98,0x4B,0x72,0xE2,0xB3,0x6C,0x6D,0xCB,0x43,0xC8,0x47,0xF2,0xA5,0x23,0x6F,0x21,0x6F,0xCE,0x16,0x8E,0xBC,0x89,0x2B,0xB5,0x6F,0x38,0xCB,0x32,0xD2,0x96,0x6C,0xEE,0x2C,0xDB,0x48,0x5B,0xF2,0xB9,0xAB,0x2C,0x11,0x2F,0xEE,0x1D,0xEE,0x52,0x07,0x25,0x43,0xFB,0xFF,0x03};

extern const uint8_t ZONE[] PROGMEM = {0x69,0x79,0x9C,0x4C,0xDC,0xB2,0x96,0xE5,0x39,0x4D,0x43,0xF6,0x6A,0x80,0x09,0x28,0x1C,0xB0,0x09,0x8A,0x01,0x1E,0x46,0x1D,0x53,0xD1,0x16,0x66,0xFE,0x66,0x4C,0xD9,0x44,0xA4,0xE9,0x9B,0xB1,0x24,0xDB,0x19,0x26,0x5B,0xDA,0x12,0xE3,0x84,0x99,0xBE,0x69,0x67,0x34,0x93,0xE1,0xB2,0xA6,0x9D,0xA1,0x54,0x18,0xC7,0xDC,0x76,0x85,0x54,0x69,0x12,0x4D,0xCB,0x15,0x4B,0xA5,0xB1,0x35,0x2D,0x77,0x08,0x59,0x2E,0xD1,0x38,0xDD,0x49,0x79,0xB5,0x6A,0x9D,0x74,0x57,0x2B,0x91,0x66,0x76,0xD3,0xD3,0xBC,0x58,0xAA,0xD9,0x49,0x4F,0x56,0x66,0xA5,0x16,0x27,0xBD,0xCD,0x8A,0x95,0x6A,0x9C,0xF4,0x56,0xCB,0x5E,0xA2,0x51,0xD2,0x9B,0x5D,0xB1,0x5B,0x2C,0x4E,0x5F,0x49,0x16,0xA6,0x55,0xFB,0xFF,0x01};


Talkie voice;
SoftwareSerial blue(10, 13); // RX | TX
String content = "";
char character;
int i=0;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  blue.begin(9600);  //Default Baud for comm, it may be different for your Module. 
  Serial.println("\n The BLUETOOTH is on");
  }
  
void loop()
{
  while (blue.available()){
    character = toupper(blue.read());
      content.concat(character);
      delay(10);
      
//  Serial.write(toupper(blue.read())); 
//  voice.say(toupper(blue.read()));
 }
 
  if (content != "") {
    
    while(i<1){
    Serial.println(content);
    voice.say());
    i++;
    }
  }

  // Feed all data from termial to bluetooth
//   if (Serial.available()){
//   blue.write(Serial.read());
//  }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 void say(const uint8_t *aWordDataAddress);
```

takes a pointer. You have several inputs, none of them is a `const uint8_t *`

https://github.com/ArminJo/Talkie/blob/c05fcf6a11c54faa38f1a20043de631ae152bfa9/src/Talkie.h#L73

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please elaborate on what change I have to make?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: you need to provide the correct type. I guess you should learn a few C++ basics befor you continue. if you don't understand what the problem is you're not ready to do this. the library comes with plenty of examples. just look how they use the say function.